# Android - Share Objects by Reference

Tags: java, android, pass-by-reference

hey people,
I have created a class which extends application to share certain variables.  Within each activity I then use an object of that class (globalstate) as so:

```
gs = (GlobalState) getApplication();
```

I then declare local variable which reference the shared ones such as:

```
boolean localStr = gs.str;
```

Now I am under the impression this would be passed a a reference and therefore any change to localStr would be reflected in str within globalstate.  However this does not seem to be the case.

Some variables created in this manor such as an array of object seem to be passed as reference and therefore any changes are reflected within globalstate however for almost every other variables (booleans, strings & ints) it seems the changes aren't reflected and therefore are being copied rather than referenced.

Have I done something wrong or is this how android works, if so how can i pass by reference?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

boolean is a value type, Java doesn't use a reference to store it. It's the same for all Java primitive types (int, long, ...). Strings are different, they are reference types but are immutable as explained by Johan Sjöberg.

That's why when using an ArrayList (for example) you will get an error if you try to use a value type like `new ArrayList<boolean>()`. But `new ArrayList<Boolean>()` will work because Boolean is a reference type, not a value type.

To avoid your problem you should use your reference everywhere (use gs.str instead of creating a local variable, localStr). I can explain it better if you don't really understand what I'm saying.

Comment: thanks mate, took a while but I changed all of my variable to gs.*

Comment: You're welcome. If we solved your problem please accept an answer (the check mark on the left).

Answer (score 1):

That's not only how android works, that's how java works. Strings are `immutable`, meaning they cannot be changed. Every time you try and modify a string a new string is created; hence the following code will leave the string named `first` unchanged:

```
String first = "first";    // First points to mem address e.g., 0x1
String second = first;     // Second also does
second = "something else"; // Second now points to 0x2, first still to 0x1
```

It's exactly the same behaviour for all primitive types (int, boolean etc).

However, when you pass a List of objects, alterations of the list *contents* will be changed everywhere. This is since your objects share the same list reference (which itself doesn't change, only it's contents).

Comment: thanks I get it now, I'm coming from a c++ background so I wasn't aware of these limitations but I've found a way around it thanks.